# Efficient search by multiple tags in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have a simple database schema and sample like so:

```
CREATE TABLE Media (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    file VARCHAR(255)
);

CREATE TABLE Tag (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    label VARCHAR(255)
);

CREATE TABLE Media_Tag (
    media_id INT,
    tag_id INT,
    PRIMARY KEY(media_id, tag_id)
);

INSERT INTO Media VALUES
    (1, "firetruck.jpg"),
    (2, "duck.jpg"),
    (3, "apple.jpg"),
    (4, "banana.jpg");

INSERT INTO Tag VALUES
    (1, "red"),
    (2, "yellow"),
    (3, "mobile"),
    (4, "immobile");

INSERT INTO Media_Tag VALUES
    (1, 1),
    (1, 3),
    (2, 2),
    (2, 3),
    (3, 1),
    (3, 4),
    (4, 2),
    (4, 4);
```

If I want to perform a search for a single tag, that's pretty easy:

```
SELECT
    m.*
FROM
    Media m
    LEFT JOIN Media_Tag mt ON mt.media_id = m.id
    LEFT JOIN Tag t ON mt.tag_id = t.id
WHERE
    t.label = ?
```

However I'm interested in doing a search by ***two*** tags. For instance, if a user searched for "red" **and** "mobile", I want it to ***only*** return "firetruck.jpg" and not "apple.jpg" (just red) or "duck.jpg" (just mobile)

---

So far I've been working on a solution like the following:

```
SELECT
    m.*
FROM
    Media m
    LEFT JOIN Media_Tag mt1 ON mt1.media_id = m.id
    LEFT JOIN Media_Tag mt2 ON mt1.media_id = mt2.media_id AND mt1.tag_id <> mt2.tag_id
    LEFT JOIN Tag t1 ON t1.id = mt1.tag_id
    LEFT JOIN Tag t2 ON t2.id = mt2.tag_id
WHERE
    t1.label = ? AND
    t2.label = ?
```

This works (and is pretty fast) except that I have to add two additional `JOIN` clauses for every tag added to the search parameters. If I don't know how many search parameters will be passed going in, I need to create a query with a "maximum" number of allowed search parameters by pre-joining X number of tables.

Is there a better solution?

I've been toying around with an idea like:

```
SELECT
    m.*
FROM
    Media m
    LEFT JOIN Media_Tag mt ON mt.media_id = m.id
    LEFT JOIN Tag t ON mt.tag_id = t.id
WHERE
    t.label IN ("red", "mobile")
GROUP BY
    <all fields on m>
HAVING
    COUNT(*) = <count-of-parameters>
```

But I ran into two issues when using this in MySQL Workbench on a sample dataset of 500,000 rows:

1. The solution with multiple `JOIN`s ran in 0.002 seconds, whereas the solution with `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` took a whole 3 seconds
2. The results of the `GROUP BY` solution seemed to be in a random order, whereas the results of the multiple `JOIN` solution came back in the primary key order of the Media table

I'm not entirely sure why the solution is so **incredibly** slow. Maybe there's something I don't understand about how `HAVING` clauses work internally. But regardless, the results coming back in a seemingly random order make this an unusable solution because I fear it will break pagination.

---

### Update 1:

I've learned that the solution with multiple `JOIN`s running in 0.002 seconds on my 500k data set was a bit of a fluke. The script that I used to add the data added a Media item, then its tags. This meant that all tags for the first 100 media items could be found at the top of the tags table. When I performed my search, I had a `LIMIT 0,25` clause to mimic pagination. This was ending my query early when it found 25 media items that matched, all of which could be found at the top of the tags table.

The `HAVING` solution, on the other hand, was scanning the **whole** tags table. This explains the 3 seconds -- that's just how long it takes to scan a table of 1 million rows.

If I modified my search to something that returned fewer than 25 Media items then suddenly it had to scan the whole table and couldn't exit early, and the `JOIN` solution took 3 seconds, as well.

### Update 2:

I don't think I was clear in my original post, so I want to expand on it. My priority here is ***efficiency***, not data integrity, code simplicity, or normalization. My current database schema **is** normalized, but I'm willing to de-normalize it if that would allow for a more efficient search.

As an experiment I amended my `Media` table with one new field:

```
UPDATE TABLE Media ADD COLUMN all_tags varchar(255);

UPDATE
    Media m
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT
            m.id,
            GROUP_CONCAT(t.label ORDER BY t.label ASC) as all_tags
        FROM
            Media b
            LEFT JOIN Media_Tag mt ON mt.media_id = m.id
            LEFT JOIN Tag t ON mt.tag_id = t.id
        GROUP BY
            m.id
        ORDER BY
            m.id
    ) j ON j.id = m.id
    SET m.all_tags = j.all_tags;
```

My new table looks like so:

```
+----+---------------+-----------------+
| id |      file     |     all_tags    |
+----+---------------+-----------------+
|  1 | firetruck.jpg |   mobile,red    |
|  2 |    duck.jpg   |  mobile,yellow  |
|  3 |   apple.jpg   |   immobile,red  |
|  4 |   banana.jpg  | immobile,yellow |
+----+---------------+-----------------+
```

I can then perform a search for tags like so:

```
SELECT * FROM Media WHERE all_tags LIKE "%tag1%tag2%...%";
```

So long as tag1, tag2, etc. are in alphabetical order (just like `all_tags` is in alphabetical order) then this will work.

This was able to perform full-table searches (searches which returned fewer than the pagination limit) in about 350 milliseconds on my data set of 500k Media items. Much better, but still not where I want to it be. I'm aiming for a response time under 100 milliseconds if possible.

Just for fun I added an index on the `all_tags` column and did an exact match search:

```
SELECT * FROM Media WHERE all_tags = "mobile,red";
```

This finished in ***0.2 milliseconds***. Unfortunately I can't rely on exact matches. Someone searching for the two tags "mobile" and "red" should also turn up a Media item with the *three* tags "cat", "mobile", and "red" -- and since "cat" comes before "mobile" alphabetically, the only way to ensure this turns up in the result set is with a starting wildcard in my `LIKE` clause, which prevents the use of an index.

I've been trying to think of more clever solutions, like having 26 columns for "all_tags_starting_with_A", "all_tags_starting_with_B", etc -- but I can't seem to wrap my head around the best option.

Comment: What does `EXPLAIN` say?

Comment: Is the column `label` on table `Tag` unique?

Comment: "...coming back in a seemingly random order..." -- You didn't specify any `ORDER BY` clause. You can't expect the rows in any particular order. The fact they came out exactly as you wanted was an "act of god", and there's no assurance it will happen in the next 5 minutes again or tomorrow.

Comment: Also, `t.label IN ("red", "mobile")` requires an "index OR" operation to be efficient in the database engine. MySQL is not as sophisticated. I've seen it in DB2 and Oracle, though.

Comment: @tadman `EXPLAIN` on the group-by / having solution says "Using where; Using temporary" / "Using where; Using index" / "NULL" for the 3 rows. I wonder if the "using temporary" is my issue?

Comment: @TheImpaler I didn't specify the column `label` as being unique in my table schema, but in my sample data it is. I should probably add that as a constraint, though.

Comment: @stevendesu If it's unique you can resolve that in advance and remove all tables `Tag` from the query just by using the corresponding `id` instead. Not sure how much of a performance improvement this can be, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution with `GROUP BY` is certainly easier to maintain so it's worth trying it but applied only to the join of `Media_Tag` and `Tag` and joining the results to `Media`:

```
SELECT m.*
FROM Media m
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT mt.media_id
  FROM Media_Tag mt INNER JOIN Tag t 
  ON mt.tag_id = t.id
  WHERE t.label IN ('red', 'mobile')
  GROUP BY mt.media_id
  HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
) t ON t.media_id = m.id;
```

I changed all the joins to `INNER` because I don't see the point of `LEFT` joins.
Or with the operator `IN` instead of a join to `Media`:

```
SELECT m.*
FROM Media m
WHERE m.id IN (
  SELECT mt.media_id
  FROM Media_Tag mt INNER JOIN Tag t 
  ON mt.tag_id = t.id
  WHERE t.label IN ('red', 'mobile')
  GROUP BY mt.media_id
  HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
);
```

Comment: This is definitely an improvement on my old solution. It ran about 10x faster, in fact! Although with it running faster I started trying queries with more tags or queries with non-existent tag pairs against my production dataset and the performance took a nosedive when I bumped `COUNT(*)` to 4 and put 4 tags in the `WHERE IN` clause. It seemed like every time I added a tag the query time doubled.

Comment: Is there a unique index on `label`? I can't say if it will help but you can try it.

Comment: So after much research and experimentation I've concluded that this is the fastest solution without de-normalizing the database. That said, I'm not opposed to de-normalizing for speed. Would you, by any chance, know a good de-normalized solution? As a fun test I created an `all_tags` column equal to `GROUP_CONCAT(t.label ORDER BY t.label ASC)` so I could do queries for `m.all_tags LIKE "%mobile%red%"` -- these queries always run in ~350 milliseconds on the 500k data set. That's just how long a table scan takes. To get faster I need indexes.

Comment: I wouldn't advice to de-normalize. Just think how you would maintain this new column after inserts, deletes and updates. If indexes can help why not? This is why they exist.

Comment: After my 8-month old woke me up at 4am I sat down at MySQL Workbench and played around for a couple of hours and found an improvement on your query. By putting the subquery in a `FROM` clause and `JOIN`ing it with the Media table, then filtering on `m.id = subq.media_id` the query ran twice as fast. Not sure why, though. I've had indexes this whole time so unfortunately I don't think there are any gains to be had there. Just for fun I'm going to try a FULLTEXT index on the "all_tags" column I made (normal indexes can't be used in `LIKE %...` queries)

Comment: Whatever works best but remember that maintenance is a very important issue and columns like all_tags are hard to maintain, especially in Mysql which does not provide even a string_split() function.

Comment: I'm using an ORM to insert data to the database, and just writing a custom query for this one particular read operation (other, faster, operations I just rely on the ORM) - so I'm hoping I can maintain the "all_tags" column by writing an on-save handler on my model and letting the ORM keep things in sync for me. It'll be of paramount importance that no one runs UPDATE queries directly against the database or bypasses the ORM, of course.

Comment: For the record, using a FULLTEXT index after only populating the first 1000 rows of the `all_tags` column seemed promising (returned in 4.5 milliseconds), but when I populated all 500k rows the performance fell off a cliff -- timed out after 30 seconds. So far the normalized solution is the best performance